# PHP/Apache dba_open file permissions

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions

I tried opening a bdb file in a directory not under the DocumentRoot(/var/www/api) in a php script(handler.php):

```
<?php
$db = dba_open("/data/bdb/current.dbm", "r", "db4");

...
?>
```

In the apache log:

```
[Mon Feb 02 23:03:59 2015] [error] [client 54.149.49.76] PHP Warning:  dba_open(/data/bdb/current.dbm): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/api/handler.php on line 6
```

/data/bdb/current.dbm was a symbolic link to /data/bdb/test.dbm

I made sure that the both directory, symbolic link, and file permission were world +rw and still received the permission error.

I did : "su - apache;php test.php" where test.php contained the dba_open call, and it worked fine. It just doesn't work under httpd.

I'm assuming I need to set some directives in apache conf in order for this to work, I just don't know exactly what.

Comment: Check all parent directories too. I.e., if /data/bdb is 755 and test.dbm is 644 but /data is 700, then you're not going to see it. (Assuming that /data is owned by a process other than the one the web server runs under.)

Comment: Also, in general, you never want to make things world writable. Especially in this case, you're explicitly opening the file read-only. Make the directory and file permissions match. (E.g., go-w)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new group (www-pub) and add the users to that group

groupadd www-pub

usermod -a -G www-pub usera ## must use -a to append to existing groups

usermod -a -G www-pub userb

groups usera ## display groups for user

Change the ownership of everything under /var/www to root:www-pub

chown -R root:www-pub /var/www ## -R for recursive

Change the permissions of all the folders to 2775

chmod 2775 /var/www ## 2=set group id, 7=rwx for owner (root), 7=rwx for group (www-pub), 5=rx for world (including apache www-data user)

Set group ID (SETGID) bit (2) causes the group (www-pub) to be copied to all new files/folders created in that folder. Other options are SETUID (4) to copy the user id, and STICKY (1) which I think lets only the owner delete files.

There's a -R recursive option, but that won't discriminate between files and folders, so you have to use find, like so:

find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +

Change all the files to 0664

find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +

Change the umask for your users to 0002

The umask controls the default file creation permissions, 0002 means files will have 664 and directories 775. Setting this (by editing the umask line at the bottom of /etc/profile in my case) means files created by one user will be writable by other users in the www-group without needing to chmod them.

Test all this by creating a file and directory and verifying the owner, group and permissions with ls -l.

Note: You'll need to logout/in for changes to your groups to take effect!